# Difficulty in understanding special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

I am following Marion Thorton.
It says as Galilean transformation $x_1'=x_1-vt $ is known to be wrong, we get $$x_1'=\gamma (x_1-vt) $$
Why are we assuming this?
What is the physical meaning of this assumption?
Why can't we derive the whole Lorentz transformation based on Einstein's 
$2$ postulates?

Comment: It's not a very good argument (and Marion-Thornton is not a very good book). You're right; they really did pull it out of nowhere, probably out of laziness or to save space.

Comment: If you want motivation, you should read literally any other introduction to special relativity, like Taylor and Wheeler, or French.

Comment: Can you suggest classical mechanics texts which have good insights in special relativity ?

Comment: I liked Morin's introduction, which is somewhat drawn out but very complete. On a more basic level, Halliday-Resnick and Kleppner-Kolenkow were good.

Comment: The Lorentz transformations are derived in several ways here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations Hopefully you'll find at least one treatment satisfactory.

Comment: @arutoregni - I would also suggest J.D. Jackson's E&M book, which has some rather detailed and thorough discussions (plus several references for further, more rigorous reading if necessary).

Comment: Forget Jackson at this level.   The book by Taylor and Wheeler is great because it focuses on the geometry of spacetime.  The first edition is better than the second which eliminates some nice discussions.

Comment: $Classical\ Mechanics$ by John Taylor and $A\ Travelers\ Guide\ to\ Spacetime$ by Thomas Moore.

Comment: I think you should get rid of that book. Galilean transformations are not wrong, but a low speed limit to Lorentz transformation.

Comment: Marion and Thornton is a classic and I will strongly disagree with @knzhou, though I don't (and wouldn't) use their chapter on relativity. Which, incidentally, is tacked on to the end after thirteen chapters of solid work on more classical theories. The book  uses a rather limited set of mathematical tools by modern standards and is not, of course, a competitor to more concise treatments suitable for graduate students nor does it used a treatment from the POV of abstract algebra, but by eschewing that stuff it form an accessible step for students not yet ready for that mathematics.